# Ldapsearch suddenly stopped authenticating against Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

We have a Linux Web application authenticating against Active Directory using ldapsearch. Everything worked well for a year, until it suddenly stopped about a week ago. Any idea about a possible cause?

We use the following command:

```
ldapsearch -n -x -H ldap://<Server> -D <SAMAccountName>@<domain> -w <Pwd>
```

So this line still works for a service account we use, but it has stopped working for "real" users in the organization.

Our current hypothesis circle around tightened security in AD that prohibits "simple authentication" for certain types of users (the -x in the command above), Group policies, funny Windows updates or changes in the use of SAMAccountName vs. UserPrincipalName. However, we can't figure out what happened.

Comment: What useful output did verbose mode `-v` provide? Have you looked into either [LDAPtracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366152(v=vs.85).aspx) or anything like [AdInsight](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/adinsight)?

Comment: What version of windows server is AD running on?  You might need to connect via TLS.

Answer (score 0):

The Active Directory server team finally confirmed, that secure (SSL/TLS) connections are now mandatory for "real" users in order to connect to Active Directory, while service accounts are allowed to authenticate without that.